# How stop setinterval in innerhtml ?

Tags: javascript

I have an div where i add time with setinterval each second. I want to stop this setinterval and set an other text in my div but the problem is my new text dispalyed one second and the time back in my div . please who can help me ?

Comment: Please go read [ask] first of all.

Comment: If you could show your code, people would be able to help you!   You likely need to call `clearInterval`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `return` keyword or store the interval-id in a variable and then use the `clearInterval` function to stop it.

HTML:

```
<div id="time"></div>
```

js (`return`):

```
let time = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    // this line stops the interval
    if(time > 10) return document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = 'finished!';
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = 'seconds: ' + time;
    time++;
}, 1000)
```

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/podapuxeho/edit?html,js,output)

js (`clearInterval`)

```
let time = 0;
let int = setInterval(() => {
// this line stops the interval
if(time === 10) clearInterval(int);
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = 'seconds: ' + time;
    time++
}, 1000)
```

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/weqihagexu/edit?html,js,output)